# SQL Query on finding Min and Max on a partition for specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query to get min and max value within a Binder(column name)in the below sample.The min and max value should only be found when Zones=N, within a group by of Binder.
Please see this sample input and output [image: sample input/output]

I tried something here, but I am not able to get it:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=225d61e8f8c20aed2411ba3b387abc54

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions with conditional logic:

```
select t1.*,
       min(case when zones = 'N' then value end) over (partition by binder) as lowest,
       max(case when zones = 'N' then value end) over (partition by binder) as highest
from t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=867c109aa7bf59c4ee5ee55e54aecd6f) is a db<>fiddle.